# Manually trigger NPM to recache the readme file?

Tags: npm, readme

Does anyone know how to instruct NPM to re-cache the readme file of a given package?

I have just republished to npm a few times but the readme which is now out of date is not updating and i cannot understand why.

Comment: Have you tried flushing your browser cache? Perhaps you can link the package? It's always updated for me immediately in my experience

Comment: Yup. No beans :/

Comment: I saw in 2016 a few posts about it too

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I've been dealing with this issue for a week and have tried all the workarounds I could find.

Comment: Nope. I contacted npm, they fixed singing and now it works.